# with beautifulsoup, how to reference the first table after a given form

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to drill down into my html, specifically I want to get the first html table that is AFTER a form that looks like:

```
<form method="POST" action="/parts.html">

..

<table ...>
...

</table>

..

</form>
```

So this table has `<tr>` for each product.

My utlimate goal here is to loop through each tablerow, and then I need to extract the product name, price, image url, etc.

What should my strategy be, and what methods in beautiful soup should I be focusing on?

Answer (score 1):

Keep reading.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Iterating%20over%20a%20Tag

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#nextSibling%20and%20previousSibling

Comment: but to get the actual text from the table cell's, I'll probably need some regex correct?

Comment: @Blankman: No.  Keep reading.  The text is an attribute of the node.  Beautiful Soup does all the parsing for you.  No regex required.